# Openrefine: copy data from text facet into excel in readable way?

Tags: excel, openrefine

I am new to OpenRefine, I created a text facet for some data as shown here:

[image: here],

I would like to copy that info into excel in two columns one with the name of the data and another with the number, butI get everything in the same column as shown here:

[image: here].

Any smart idea to not fix it manually?

Answer (score 3):

If you click the button in the top left of the facet that says "10 choices" it will give you the facet choices as tab separated values, which you can copy directly into a spreadsheet, and should format as two columns.

Comment: this is the stuff the dreams are made of